# Problem with updating modules (check updates)

Tags: updating

I have Drupal 7.26 with Commons 7.x-3.9. Recentyl manual update of modules is not working. When going to "Modules" - "Update" I'm getting something like:

`Last checked: 4 days 58 min ago (Check manually)`

and this is the last time I've been able to check updates (just before Durpal core update).

When I use "Check manually", the page with progress bar appears where progress bar is always "100%" and messages say:

`Trying to check available update data ...
Checking available update data ...`

After short while it returns to "Update" page with:

`Last checked: 8 hours 5 min ago (Check manually)
There was a problem getting update information. Try again later.`

No updates visible, no errors in log.

Any ideas?

Comment: When did that happen? After upgrading Drupal core? I would suggest to check if your webserver (apache?) can access external URLs. Maybe something changed in your firewall/proxy on the server...

Comment: It happened after upgrading Drupal Commons site from version 7.x-3.6 to 3.9. Nothing changed in the Apache installation. This same Apache instance is used to run another Drupal web site and there is no problem with updates. It seems that something wrong with this particular version and probably Commons profile but module update is a core Drupal method.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved through cleaning cache_update table (execute SQL query "delete from cache_update;" through phpmyadmin or mysql workbench)

Comment: Just had exactly the same thing; had to truncate the cache_update table. Flushing caches did not fix it!

Comment: Same, full cache clear did nothing, had to truncate the cache_update table directly. Works fine now.